# Which design patterns can be applied to the configuration settings problem?

Tags: design-patterns, configuration, configuration-files, application-settings

In large and complex software products managing configurable settings becomes a major pain. Two approaches I've seen to the problem are:

- have each component in the system load its own configuration from config files or registry settings.
- have a settings loader class that loads all the configurable system settings and have each component query the settings loader for its settings.

These approaches both feel wrong to me.

**Are there any design patterns that could be used to simplify the problem?** Maybe something that would take advantage of the dependency injection technique.

Comment: Why do you think option 2 is wrong?

Comment: It's usually implemented as a singleton, though there are other ways to implement it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I prefer to create an interface for setting query, loading, and saving.  By using dependency injection, I can inject this into each component that requires it.

This allows flexibility in terms of replacing the configuration strategy, and gives a common base for everything to work from.  I prefer this to a single, global "settings loader" (your option 2), especially since I can override the configuration mechanism for a single component if I absolutely need to do so.

Comment: hello,it will be nice if u share some sample :)

Comment: @issamux someone provided a code sample based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776593/11537143)

Answer (score 22):

I currently work on a system where the configuration is managed by one global singleton object that keeps a map of configuration keys to values.  In general,  I wish it hadn't been done this way because it can cause concurrency bottlenecks in the system and it's sloppy for unit testing, etc.

I think Reed Copsey has the right of it (I voted him up), but I would definitely recommend reading Martin Fowler's great article on dependency injection:

http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

A slight addendum too...if you want to do any mock object type unit testing, dependency injection is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It seems that decorator match your needs. You can create a Serializable decorator that will be able to make classes serializable in their own way. Strategy can be used to make all objects have their strategy for serialization. Those objects that do not need to be serialized can use ignore strategy. Those that only need to serialize their fields OnlyFields strategy and so on. You`ll be flexible with adding new things to your config. Sure as all approaches this have it`s pros and cons.

Answer (score 5):

How about this. You define an interface Configurable with a single method configure(configuration). The configuration argument is simply a hashtable which associates the names of configuration parameters with their values.

Root objects can create a configuration hashtable in whatever way they want (ex: reading it from a config file). This hashtable may contain configuration parameters for the root object iselft, plus any parameter that one of its components, sub-components, sub-sub-components (etc) might use.

The root object then invokes configure(configuration) on all of its configurable components.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple implementation of an interface that defines the config loader. Basically strategy pattern where you can define one basic interface as configLoader and then further different implementations such as FileSystemLoader, ClasspathLoader, EnvVariablesLoader etc.
Details at this [link](https://blog.stackhunter.com/2014/01/14/how-to-load-config-files-with-the-strategy-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

I usually have controllers that read user settings (stored in key-value pairs locally, accessed via a `UserSettings` class).
Each controller is responsible for reading the statically defined user settings. They then inject needed dependencies into views (e.g. themes, language packs) or into other controllers (e.g. persistence mechanisms, serialization, strategies).
How the user settings are stored is platform dependent (e.g. local storage for web, XML files for desktop).