# What is the best way to get instance of a class from AutoFac when constructor injection has parameters known at configuration and runtime

Tags: c#, configuration, settings, autofac

I found two related posts that are close to my question but still not answer what I'm looking for.

[Which design patterns can be applied to the configuration settings problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314730/which-design-patterns-can-be-applied-to-the-configuration-settings-problem)

[Should my program's "services" be responsible to get their own configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450788/should-my-programs-services-be-responsible-to-get-their-own-configuration?lq=1)

I have an application using AutoFac as DI container and ran into the following problem. I have classes I register with AutoFac at startup, but some constructor parameters are only known during runtime. I made up a sample to show my intension. The comment shows the location in code where I want to retrieve an instance of a class and inject some configuration data at this point in time.

The idea behind it is to separate the implementation of a generic settings provider from the configuration of certain classes. The configuration should be retrieved from the settings provider (ISettingsProvider), be converted to a class related settings class (FooSettings) and then be injected at creation time into that class (Foo).

Any suggestions on how to do this?

My sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Autofac;

namespace FooNamespace
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<SettingsProvider>().As<ISettingsProvider>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<AnotherService>().As<IAnotherService>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>();
            builder.RegisterType<ClientClass>();

            var container = builder.Build();

            var myClient = container.Resolve<ClientClass>();

            myClient.DoSomething();

        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        private FooSettings _settings;
        private IAnotherService _anotherService;

        public Foo(IAnotherService anotherService, FooSettings settings)
        {
            _anotherService = anotherService;
            _settings = settings;
        }
    }

    public class FooSettings
    {
        public string SettingA { get; private set; }
        public string SettingB { get; private set; }
        public FooSettings(string settingA, string settingB)
        {
            SettingA = settingA;
            SettingB = settingB;
        }
    }

    public class ClientClass
    {
        private readonly ISettingsProvider _settingsProvider;

        public ClientClass(ISettingsProvider settingsProvider)
        {
            _settingsProvider = settingsProvider;
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var providerSettings = _settingsProvider.GetSettings("fooSettings");

            var fooSettings = new FooSettings(providerSettings[0], providerSettings[1]);

            // what is the best way to get an instance of foo with the fooSettings set at runtime
            // when Foo and IAnotherService have been registered with AutoFac
        }

    }

    public interface ISettingsProvider
    {
        string[] GetSettings(string settingsGroup);
    }

    class SettingsProvider : ISettingsProvider
    {

        public string[] GetSettings(string settingsGroup)
        {
            return new string[2] {"valueA", "valueB"};
        }
    }

    public interface IAnotherService
    {

    }

    class AnotherService : IAnotherService
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [Abstract Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)  always when I need a runtime value to be injected as dependency.

Define a factory interface

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
    Foo CreateFoo();
}
```

Implement the interface with the help of [Delegate Factories](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) support provided by autofac. If you take a dependency on any delegate, autofac will create the implementation for you with all the dependencies except the dependencies which the delegate takes in.

```
public class FooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    private readonly Func<FooSettings, Foo> creationFunc;
    private readonly ISettingsProvider settingsProvider;
    public FooFactory(Func<FooSettings, Foo> creationFunc, ISettingsProvider settingsProvider)
    {
        if (creationFunc == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("creationFunc");
        if (settingsProvider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("settingsProvider");

        this.creationFunc = creationFunc;
        this.settingsProvider = settingsProvider;
    }

    public Foo CreateFoo()
    { 
        var providerSettings = settingsProvider.GetSettings("fooSettings");
        var fooSettings = new FooSettings(providerSettings[0], providerSettings[1]);
        return creationFunc(fooSettings);
    }
}
```

Take a dependency on `IFooFactory` instead of `ISettingsProvider`

```
public class ClientClass
{
    private readonly IFooFactory fooFactory;
    public ClientClass(IFooFactory fooFactory)
    {
        this.fooFactory = fooFactory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var foo = fooFactory.CreateFoo();
       //Do whatever with foo
       //Your foo is now injected with another service and settings too:)
    }
}
```

And of course register the factory

```
builder.RegisterType<FooFactory>().As<IFooFactory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `FooSettingsProvider` that will depends on `SettingsProvider` and register a lambda as a `FooSettings`.

For example :

```
public interface ISettingsProvider<TSettings> where TSettings : ISettings
{
    TSettings Settings { get; }
}
public class FooSettingsProvider : ISettingsProvider<FooSettings>
{
    public FooSettingsProvider(SettingsProvider settingsProvider)
    {
        this._settingsProvider = settingsProvider;
        this._settings = new Lazy<FooSettings>(this.InitializeSettings);
    }


    private readonly SettingsProvider _settingsProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<FooSettings> _settings;

    public FooSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return this._settings.Value;
        }
    }

    private FooSettings InitializeSettings()
    {
        var providerSettings = this._settingsProvider.GetSettings("fooSettings");
        var fooSettings = new FooSettings(providerSettings[0], providerSettings[1]);

        return fooSettings;
    }
}
```

To register your FooSettings you can use this registration :

```
builder.RegisterType<FooSettingsProvider>()
        .As<ISettingsProvider<FooSettings>>();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISettingsProvider<FooSettings>>().Settings)
        .As<FooSettings>();
```