# Recommended pattern for defining application parameters and configuration in App Engine modules

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have parameters that control thresholds/limits/etc. for my App Engine handlers.  At first I'd like to try to centralize the important variables in a sensible place so they're easy to find and update, while also still being efficient to access.  Secondly, my initial settings for those parameters will likely need tweaked, and perhaps even "in production" so one feature of the pattern would be "online" update.

My question:  Is there a common/recommended pattern for achieving this?  I see threads on "passing configuration", like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710758/python-pattern-for-sharing-configuration-throughout-application).  But its not in the context of App Engine.

Some options in my head:

1. Follow a common configuration pattern for python modules, and when I need to update the values I need to basically deploy a new version of my app.  Downside is any live instances won't pick up on this change.
2. Have the config populated into some sort "ConfigEntity" datastore entity.  I could use the App Engine console to modify this value on the fly?  With MEMCACHE maybe the efficiency to access the value wouldn't be an issue?

Comment: The easiest method would be to just redeploy your app, since App Engine actually kills all active instances on deployment.

Comment: Thanks @IgorKharin... I didn't know a redeploy killed running instances.  That helps to know.  I'll follow that guidance...