# python module loaded twice ruins config singleton

Tags: python, singleton, python-import, python-module

I followed [Python pattern for sharing configuration throughout application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710758/python-pattern-for-sharing-configuration-throughout-application) and failed once I tried using it from a different package (folder), can anyone offer a fix?

tree:

```
|-- my_app
|   |-- config.py
|   |-- main.py
|   |-- my_package
|   |   |-- also.py
```

command line: `python -m my_app.main`

both main.py and also.py need to use the global configuration from config.py. code in both of them:

```
import config
print("config", config)
```

displays 2 different things!!! main.py says:

```
('config', <module 'my_app.config' from 'my_app/config.pyc'>)
```

and also.py says:

```
('config', <module 'config' from '/tmp/project/my_app/config.pyc'>)
```

and it breaks the shared configuration of course :(

I tried following [traps](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html) but couldn't find anything obvious...

Comment: It's very obviously the "double import trap" documented in your link. You didn't specify which Python version you were using, but changing both imports to `from myapp import config` might solve the problem.

Comment: thanks @brunodesthuilliers - that fixed the problem indeed (wasn't obvious to me :) .

Comment: I discovered this trap the hard way with early django versions so I now know how to spot it ;-)  The telltale sign is the difference in module path.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - help! now my py.test wont run! `py.test my_app/tests` throws `No module named my_app`

Comment: This is another distinct problem so please open a new question with the relevant details (including the full traceback) - but first search for similar question, since it's certainly already been asked here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - agree, found the solution - I should use `python -m pytest my_app/tests` instead