# How to use io.airlift.configuration?

Tags: design-patterns, configuration, dependency-injection, presto

Following up on:
[Which design patterns can be applied to the configuration settings problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314730/which-design-patterns-can-be-applied-to-the-configuration-settings-problem)

Has anyone used the io.airlift.configuration package? It uses DI and is primarily used in Presto? I was hunting online but there seems to be very minimal documentation on its usage and capabilities. If anybody could provide some pointers that would be really helpful.

Generally speaking: Conf classes in Hadoop and Hive seem extremely cluttered and bloated. The distributed and modular approach that the Presto team at facebook has taken seems much cleaner. Is there a well known config package that one can use in Java?